# Как получить объект <T> из Observable<T>?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Проект Angular а-ля новостной портал.

```
export class CategoriesService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getCategories(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('./assets/categories.json');
  }

  getCategory(id: number | string): Observable<Category> {
    return this.getCategories()
      .pipe(
        map((categories: Array<Category>) =>  categories.find(category => category.id === +id)),
        catchError(err => Observable.throw('Error in getCategory method'))
      );
  }
}
```

Сервис читает локальный categories.json содержащий массив объектов Category и возвращает Observable.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Science",
    "description": "Posts for the most curious ones..",
    "url": "science",
    "backgroundImageURL": "/images/2019/07/photo-617a33825bc6.jpeg"
  },
....
```

Компонент NewsList получает список новостей из NewsService и отображает. У каждой новости Article есть categoryId: number. Я в шаблоне хочу получить значение поля title для передаваемого categoryId.

```
<p>{{getCategory(article.categoryId)}}</p>
```

Компонент NewsList:

```
export class NewsListComponent implements OnInit {

  news$: Observable<Array<Article>>;

  constructor(private newsService: NewsService,
              private categoriesService: CategoriesService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.news$ = this.newsService.getNews();
  }

  getCategory(categoryId: number | string):string {
    return this.categoriesService.getCategory(categoryId);
  }
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в

```
getCategory(categoryId: number | string):string {
    return this.categoriesService.getCategory(categoryId);
  }
```

получить поле title?
Пробовал так:

```
getCategory(categoryId: number | string) {
    return this.categoriesService.getCategory(categoryId).pipe(map(cat => cat.title));
  }
```

И так:

```
getCategory(categoryId: number | string) {
    let category;
    this.categoriesService.getCategory(categoryId).pipe(map(c => category = c.title));
    return category;
  }
```

К сожалению, не работает.

Comment: чтобы получить значение из Observable в коде нужен subscribe, а в разметке `async` pipe

Comment: Да, в таком варианте:

`export class NewsListComponent implements OnInit {

  category: string;
  ...

  getCategory(categoryId: number | string) {
    this.categoriesService.getCategory(categoryId).subscribe(c => this.category = c.title);
    return this.category;
  }
}`
работает, значение поля присваивается. Но! Во-первых, присваивается одно и то же значение title всем элементам, а не для каждого своё. Во-вторых, браузер начинает зависать. Подозреваю нужно вызвать unsubscribe(), но где?

Comment: Нужен [mcve], по приведенному коду ничего не должно зависать